# Plotting surface

Tags: plotting, differential-geometry

Does anyone know how to plot this image? I am writing an example for [Kenmotsu's representation theorem](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01428799) , for $\varphi :%
%TCIMACRO{\U{2102} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{C}
%EndExpansion
-\{0\}\rightarrow 
%TCIMACRO{\U{2102} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{C}
%EndExpansion
$, $\varphi (z)=\frac{1}{\bar{z}^{2}}.$ And this image corresponds to the surface with $\varphi (z)=-\frac{1}{\bar{z}^{2}}$ and $%
H=1$. I am using Mathematica for only a couple days and I don't know what I'm supposed to write to generate it. I appreciate any advice and help! Thank you!

[image]

after a fairly long calculation I get to:
[image]

and I assume that using this equation plots the image but I don't realize how I need to write this in Mathematica.

complex equation:
[image]

Comment: Can you give more details?

Comment: Please post the details about the original complex equation instead of only the real equation.

Comment: it's posted now.

Comment: @user981656: Do you really mean an indefinite integral?

Comment: yes, that's how it's supposed to be. :)

Comment: @user981656:  Please give the definition of $\int f(z,\bar{z})\,dz$. As I remember it, I have never seen it.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code and formulas as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: hi @MichaelE2, I didn't posted any code because initially I tried to plot the image with a code similar to user64494 , but as the surface came out completely different I considered that there was no point in putting it here. sorry for the inconvenience, I didn't want to upset anyone.

Comment: I meant in particular the code for the formula for $X(z)$, which you assume is correct. You are more likely to get more people to try to plot it for you if they can copy-paste instead of transcribing from browser to Mma. That said, incorrect code often reveals a misconception that you might like to have cleared up, which is a separate reason for posting code. (The first comment was meant to be generally helpful. You aren't required to post code, but some people will just skip a problem with no code and go on to something easier to deal with. Or go back to work. :)

Answer (score 3):

(This is too long for a comment.)

If you look at the result of

```
(Re[f[u + I v]] + I Im[f[u + I v]]) (\[DifferentialD] u + I \[DifferentialD] v) // Expand
   I \[DifferentialD]u Im[f[u + I v]] - \[DifferentialD]v Im[f[u + I v]] +
   \[DifferentialD]u Re[f[u + I v]] + I \[DifferentialD]v Re[f[u + I v]]
```

this gives a hint on how to compute $\Re\int f(z,\bar{z})\,\mathrm dz$:

```
parts = Simplify[ComplexExpand[ReIm[1/z^3 {(1 - Conjugate[z]^-4)/(1 + (z Conjugate[z])^-2)^2,
                                           I (1 + Conjugate[z]^-4)/(1 + (z Conjugate[z])^-2)^2,
                                           (2 Conjugate[z]^-2)/(1 + (z Conjugate[z])^-2)^2} /.
                                    z -> u + I v], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]]
   {{(u (-1 + u^4 - 2 u^2 v^2 - 3 v^4))/(1 + u^4 + 2 u^2 v^2 + v^4)^2,
     (v (-1 - 3 u^4 - 2 u^2 v^2 + v^4))/(1 + u^4 + 2 u^2 v^2 + v^4)^2},
    {-((v (1 - 3 u^4 - 2 u^2 v^2 + v^4))/(1 + u^4 + 2 u^2 v^2 + v^4)^2),
     (u + u^5 - 2 u^3 v^2 - 3 u v^4)/(1 + u^4 + 2 u^2 v^2 + v^4)^2},
    {(2 u (u^2 + v^2))/(1 + u^4 + 2 u^2 v^2 + v^4)^2,
     -((2 v (u^2 + v^2))/(1 + u^4 + 2 u^2 v^2 + v^4)^2)}}

FullSimplify[(MapThread[Integrate, {#, {u, v}}] & /@ parts) . {1, -1}]
   {(-u^2 + v^2)/(1 + (u^2 + v^2)^2), -((2 u v)/(1 + (u^2 + v^2)^2)), -(1/(1 + (u^2 + v^2)^2))}
```

which you should then multiply by a factor of $\frac2{H}$.

Verify the constant curvature property:

```
Simplify[ResourceFunction["MeanCurvature"][2 {(-u^2 + v^2)/(1 + (u^2 + v^2)^2),
                                              -((2 u v)/(1 + (u^2 + v^2)^2)),
                                              -(1/(1 + (u^2 + v^2)^2))}, {u, v}],
         u ∈ Reals && v ∈ Reals]
   1
```

As an exercise, why is the following result expected?

```
GroebnerBasis[Thread[{x, y, z} == 2 {(-u^2 + v^2)/(1 + (u^2 + v^2)^2),
                                     -((2 u v)/(1 + (u^2 + v^2)^2)),
                                     -(1/(1 + (u^2 + v^2)^2))}],
              {x, y, z}, {u, v}] // Simplify
   {x^2 + y^2 + z (2 + z)}
```

Answer (score 0):

This (?[minimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surface)) surface in  three dimensions can be plotted in such ways:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{-(x^2 - y^2)*(1 - (x^2 + y^2)^2)/(1 + (x^2 + y^2)^2), 
-2*x*y*(1 - (x^2 + y^2)^2)/(1 + (x^2 + y^2)^2), 
(x^2 +  y^2)^2/(1 + (x^2 + y^2)^2)}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

or switching to the polar coordinates

```
ParametricPlot3D[{-(x^2 - y^2)*(1 - (x^2 + y^2)^2)/(1 + (x^2 + y^2)^2), -2*x*
y*(1 - (x^2 + y^2)^2)/(1 + (x^2 + y^2)^2), (x^2 +  y^2)^2/(1 + (x^2 + y^2)^2)} 
/. {x -> r*Cos[t], y -> r*Sin[t]}, {r, 0, 3/2}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

[image]

See the documentation for more info.

Comment: The mention of Kenmotsu (as well as the other questions OP asked) was enough of a reminder for me that OP is dealing with surfaces of constant mean curvature, and minimal surfaces are of course a special case of that.